# how can I run this select statement inside a select statement without any problems?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a select statement that is pulling calculations, and one of the many things is a select in of itself.  this is what I am trying to run:

```
           SELECT Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.COMBINED_CASES) AS Total_Volume, 
   TRUNC(Avg(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.COMBINED_CASES), 2) AS Average_Volume, 
   Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.CASES_PRODUCED) AS Producivity, 
   Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.STOCKING_LEVEL) AS Total_Inventory, 
   TRUNC(Avg(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.STOCKING_LEVEL), 2) AS Average_Inventory, 
   Count(DISTINCT AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.LOC_ID) AS Nbr_of_plants, 
   TRUNC(Avg(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.health_score), 2) AS Network_Capacity, 
   Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.Current_SQFT) AS total_SQFT, 
   Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.Current_AVAIL_SQFT) AS SumOfCurrent_AVAIL_SQFT, 
   Count(DISTINCT AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.Routes) AS nbr_of_Route, 
   TRUNC(Avg(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.Routes), 2) AS Avg_nbr_Routes, 
   TRUNC(Avg(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.DockDoor_Utilization), 2) AS AvgOfDockDoor_Utilization, 
     Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.Layer_Pickers) AS SumOfLayer_Pickers, 
     Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.nbr_canopies) AS SumOfnbr_canopies, 
     Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.nbr_DriveTHRUS) AS SumOfnbr_DrivETHRUS, 
   (Select Sum(MAX_TRUCKS_IN_CANOPY + MAX_TRUCKS_IN_DT_LOADING) from icam_locations), 
     Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.nbr_Returns) AS SumOfnbr_Returns, 
     TRUNC(Avg(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.nbr_Returns), 2) AS AvgOfnbr_Returns, 
     trunc((Sum(OUT_OF_STOCK_QTY) / Sum(combined_cases)), 2) AS Out_of_Stock_Pct, 
     Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.CountOfINVEN_ID) AS SumOfCountOfINVEN_ID, 
     SUM(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.SKU_CAPACITY) AS SUMOfSKU_CAPACITY, 
     Sum(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.Sales) AS SumOfSales, 
     TRUNC(Avg(AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.Sales), 2) AS AvgOfSales 
           FROM AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY
       INNER JOIN ICAM_LOCATIONS
      ON AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.LOC_ID = ICAM_LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID
    WHERE 
 TRIM((FSCL_YR_NUM * 100) +(FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)) >= TRIM(('&PARM_FROM_DATE')) 
AND TRIM((FSCL_YR_NUM * 100) +(FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)) <= TRIM(('&PARM_TO_DATE')) 
      ORDER BY AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.LOC_ID
```

I was playing with it and also tried it as follows:

```
    WITH STUFF_COUNT AS
(
SELECT ICAM_LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID, (MAX_TRUCKS_IN_CANOPY+ MAX_TRUCKS_IN_DT_LOADING) AS VAL2 
 FROM  ICAM_LOCATIONS
GROUP BY LOCATION_ID, MAX_TRUCKS_IN_CANOPY, MAX_TRUCKS_IN_DT_LOADING 
)
SELECT SUM(Z.VAL2),
   Sum(S.COMBINED_CASES) AS Total_Volume, 
   TRUNC(Avg(S.COMBINED_CASES), 2) AS Average_Volume, 
   Sum(S.CASES_PRODUCED) AS Producivity, 
   Sum(S.STOCKING_LEVEL) AS Total_Inventory, 
   TRUNC(Avg(S.STOCKING_LEVEL), 2) AS Average_Inventory, 
   Count(DISTINCT S.LOC_ID) AS Nbr_of_plants, 
   TRUNC(Avg(S.health_score), 2) AS Network_Capacity, 
   Sum(S.Current_SQFT) AS total_SQFT, 
   Sum(S.Current_AVAIL_SQFT) AS SumOfCurrent_AVAIL_SQFT, 
   Count(DISTINCT S.Routes) AS nbr_of_Route, 
   TRUNC(Avg(S.Routes), 2) AS Avg_nbr_Routes, 
   TRUNC(Avg(S.DockDoor_Utilization), 2) AS AvgOfDockDoor_Utilization, 
   Sum(S.Layer_Pickers) AS SumOfLayer_Pickers, 
   Sum(S.nbr_canopies) AS SumOfnbr_canopies, 
   SUM(S.NBR_DRIVETHRUS) AS SUMOFNBR_DRIVETHRUS, 
   Sum(S.nbr_Returns) AS SumOfnbr_Returns, 
   TRUNC(Avg(S.nbr_Returns), 2) AS AvgOfnbr_Returns, 
   trunc((Sum(OUT_OF_STOCK_QTY) / Sum(combined_cases)), 2) AS Out_of_Stock_Pct, 
   Sum(S.CountOfINVEN_ID) AS SumOfCountOfINVEN_ID, 
   SUM(S.SKU_CAPACITY) AS SUMOfSKU_CAPACITY, 
   Sum(S.Sales) AS SumOfSales, 
   TRUNC(AVG(S.SALES), 2) AS AVGOFSALES 
 FROM  AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY S, ICAM_LOCATIONS D, STUFF_COUNT Z
WHERE S.LOC_ID = D.LOCATION_ID
AND TRIM((FSCL_YR_NUM * 100) +(FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)) >= TRIM(('&PARM_FROM_DATE')) 
AND TRIM((FSCL_YR_NUM * 100) +(FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)) <= TRIM(('&PARM_TO_DATE'))
  ORDER BY S.LOC_ID;
```

neither of which has givin me desired results, but when I run them seperately, I get what is needed.  Also, I am unable to create any additional tables to write too or the like.  it appearently needs to be done as a whole (as demanded by the gods it is, or atleast by the paying company)

I typically get this error, and nome other random ones when I try adjustinng it.

SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
ORDER BY S.LOC_ID
```

You cannot use there any cols which are not in the GROUP BY (or not an aggregate function / a select expr alias / a column number, for example `ORDER BY 1`)

P.S. and it doesn't make any sense in this query

Comment: I removed that group by. When I run it like that, it does not error out (YAY!), but the particular select statement returns a value of 1120 instead of 28 (which is the answer looking for) when run by itself